# react js button disable according to checking status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click the edit form, I am checking the form status. In the edit, status='Draft'. If status is draft, button is disabled.

```
  <Button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={location.state.status == 'Draft'} type="button" onClick={() => saveAsDraftInvoice(values)}>
              <i className="mdi mdi-table-edit"></i> Save as Draft
            </Button>
```

Above code is working well. button is disabled correctly. But when i go to add new record, error said "

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"
```

check below screen shot
[image]

reason is, when I edit form, status is have inside the object. When I go to save new record that 'status' undefine. how I fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the object exists every step of the way to prevent trying to access an undefined value:

`disabled={location && location.state && location.state.status == 'Draft'}`

If location or state aren't defined the `disabled` prop will be false.

Comment: Marquez Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Remember that React it's javascript :) good luck

Answer (score 1):

For instance just check if `status` property exists.

It can be done with additional condition: 
`location.state && location.state.status == 'Draft'`

or with optional chaining: 
`location.state?.status == 'Draft'`

```
<Button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={location.state && location.state.status == 'Draft'} type="button" onClick={() => saveAsDraftInvoice(values)}>
              <i className="mdi mdi-table-edit"></i> Save as Draft
            </Button>
```

or

```
<Button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={location.state?.status == 'Draft'} type="button" onClick={() => saveAsDraftInvoice(values)}>
              <i className="mdi mdi-table-edit"></i> Save as Draft
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining on the location object as below!

disabled={location?.state?.status == 'Draft'}